# Logic of interaction among models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, refactoring, models

I'm studying Rails and am now trying to organize interaction among models. What I've written works, but I think that the code smells bad.

For example, I have two models with database tables `Parcel` and `Warehouse`. When I create a new Parcel, I want to increase the `:current_weight` of the Warehouse instance which is related to this new Parcel.

Again, everything works, but this type of code, interaction between two different objects, will be used frequently and something deep in my mind says: "Dude, this code sucks and will cause problems in the future!".

Maybe there are some good practices to organize or refactor it? Maybe it's
better to create a universal module for such interactions, or even create
`method_missing` logic to use methods with universal `put_`, `remove_`,
`check_`, like `warehouse.put_parcel` and `warehouse.remove_parcel`.

In ruby console:

```
parcel = Parcel.new
parcel.weight = 10
parcel.warehouse_id = 1
parcel.save

# Create parcel and increase :current_weight of related warehouse by 10 after save
```

warehouse.rb:

```
class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parcels
  attr_accessible :name, :current_weight
end
```

parcel.rb:

```
class Parcel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :warehouse
    belongs_to :vehicle
  attr_accessible :name, :weight, :warehouse_id, :vehicle_id

  after_save :set_current_weight

  #Bad code:
  def set_current_weight
    @wh = self.warehouse
    @wh.current_weight = @wh.current_weight + self.weight
    @wh.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
warehouse.parcels.sum(:weight)
```

That way you are running a 'live' query based on the current data, rather the incrementing.

Slightly more terse version of your current model too:

```
  def set_current_weight
    @wh = self.warehouse
    @wh.current_weight += self.weight
    @wh.save
  end
```

Comment: Thanks!
So, this 'live' query should be called after parcel save or update in Parcel model? Or it's better to implement it in Warehouse model?
What if there are 100500 parcels in the warehouse? Isn't it heavy for SQL?

Comment: Personally I would just run the query whenever I wanted to know the current weight.  The SUM command isn't particularly 'heavy' for even 100,000 rows, especially when you're not doing any other data manipulation.  Just to clarify, I don't mean defining it as a method in any model, the underlying logic is build in to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

The `current_weight` of the warehouse is really not part of a `Parcel` object mandate. You have also given it more than one reason to change. Thus, this breaks the [single responsibility principle](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SrpInRuby).

I would suggest removing `:current_weight` and `set_current_weight` altogether. Get the total weight inside warehouse like this:

```
def Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parcels
  # ...

  def current_weight
    parcels.sum(:weight)
  end
end
```

As suggested by @muttonlamb in his post.